# Jquery code NOT working on Apple mobile devices (Safari and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, safari

I have a super standard errors box that pops up when there's an invalid submission, and the user can then close out of this box. So in other words....

HTML

```
<!-- Errors box -->
<div class="container alerts-container" id="order-errors" style="display:none;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
      <p><strong>Sorry about that, the order didn't go through because of the following reasons:</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 remove-col" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 labeler">
      <ul>
        <% if @order.errors.any? %>
          <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %> 
        <% end %>
        <% if flash[:danger].present? %>
          <li><%= flash[:danger] %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Rendered:

```
<div class="container alerts-container" id="order-errors" style="display: block;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
      <p><strong>Sorry about that, the order didn't go through because of the following reasons:</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 remove-col">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 labeler">
      <ul><li>Rental end date has to be on or after rental start date</li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
// Close errors box
$(document).on("click", "#order-errors .glyphicon-remove", function(e) {
  $('#order-errors').slideUp()
})
```

On Safari/Chrome/Firefox on a MacBook, or on Chrome/Firefox on PC, and on Chrome/Firefox on Android it works fine. But on Safari/Chrome on any Apple mobile device it does NOT work. Any thoughts? Note that on a Safari emulator on MacBook it works fine as well.

To test the code:

```
1. Go to https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/orders
2. Hit the Cart button at top left
3. Order errors will pop up in orange
4. Try to "x" out of the order errors box, it will/ will not work per above
```

Comment: You're `span` `glyphicon-remove` element really should be a semantically interactive element, like `button`. Most-likely if it were you would have no issue.

Comment: ^ Probably a better duplicate.

Comment: adding js to button really helped me on safari, thanks